# Returning (AWSTask <NSString *>) without errors

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I have the following code from the AWS documentation:

@implementation DeveloperAuthenticatedIdentityProvider
/*
 * Use the token method to communicate with your backend to get an
 * identityId and token.
 */

```
- (AWSTask <NSString*>) token {
    //Write code to call your backend:
    //Pass username/password to backend or some sort of token to authenticate user
    //If successful, from backend call getOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity with logins map 
    //containing "your.provider.name":"enduser.username"
    //Return the identity id and token to client
    //You can use AWSTaskCompletionSource to do this asynchronously

    // Set the identity id and return the token
    self.identityId = response.identityId;
    return [AWSTask taskWithResult:response.token];
}

@end
```

How do I return (AWSTask )? I have the token through another method and it is in NSString *token form.

Documentation:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/developer-authenticated-identities.html

Comment: It appears the docs have a typo and the source in git states this: - (AWSTask<NSString *> *)token

Comment: Did resolving that docs issue fix it? I can forward that on.